# Eigenvalues of a compact operator with modulus greater than $\epsilon$ is finite

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, compact-operators

Consider the following fragments from Murphy's "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory":
[image: q ]1]

In the above proof of theorem 2.4.5., how does theorem 1.4.11 imply that the set $S$ is finite? I guess it has something to do with the non-zero points of $\sigma(u)$ being isolated?

Comment: Every non-zero point of $\sigma(u)$ is isolated. Since every point of $S$ has distance $≥\epsilon$ to $0$ you find that every point in $S$ is isolated and since $S$ is closed in $\Bbb C$ you get that $S$ is discrete. Further $S$ is bounded since it is contained in the spectrum of an operator. How many discrete and boudned subsets of $\Bbb C$ do you know?

Comment: @s.harp With discrete you mean that it has the discrete topology?

Comment: With discrete in mean "discrete in $\Bbb C$", which means every point in $\Bbb C$ has a neighbourhood intersecting $S$ at most once. (This is equivalent to $S$ having the discrete topology and being closed in $\Bbb C$)

Comment: @s.harp I guess a bounded discrete subset must be finite, but I'm not sure how I can prove it. Maybe using a compactness argument? Such a set must be compact (because it is complete due to discreteness and totally bounded since we work in $\Bbb{C}$) and by discreteness again we must have finiteness or we would have an open cover of singeltons that has no finite subcover. Does that look ok?

Comment: Thats right.${}$

Comment: @s.harp Thanks for the help. You can make that an answer if you like.

Comment: I edited the post a bit to help searchability. I don't know if somebody will ever find it when they have trouble with this theorem 2.4.5., but I guess it doesn't hurt.

Comment: @s.harp Thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $S$. Since $S$ is bounded in $\Bbb C$ it is a bounded sequence and as such admits a convergent subsequence, so assume it converges. Further $|x_n|≥\epsilon$ for all $n$ so $x_n$ cannot converge to $0$. Since $S=\sigma(u)\cap \{ x\in\Bbb C\mid |x|≥\epsilon \}$ is closed the limit must also lie in $S$. But every point of $S$ is isolated and as such cannot be the limit of other points and $x_n$ must be eventually constant (ie $S$ is discrete in $\Bbb C$).

This implies $S$ is finite, for otherwise there must be a sequence without a constant subsequence.

Comment: I deleted my comment. I will delete this one too if you have seen it.